# Snowflake Connection String for Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My company is switching from an Oracle 'on-prem' data warehouse to Snowflake cloud storage.

I support MANY **Microsoft Access** apps that use **pass-through** queries which use a simple string in the connection string property. Once a user had downloaded the appropriate Oracle Admin (X64) client, they are in business.

With snowflake, the client software is also a simple download.  I am stuck, however, getting the connection string to work.  Here is where I'm currently at:

`ODBC;DRIVER={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};SERVER=xxxx.us-east-1.privatelink.snowflakecomputing.com;UID=xxx@xxx.com;PWD=xxx;WH=XYZ;DATABASE=XYZ;ROLE=XYZ`

(This string returns error: ODBC--call failed.  No active warehouse selected in the current session.  Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command. (#606))

**Has anyone successfully managed to connect a Microsoft Access Pass-through query to Snowflake and retrieve results?**

*(Please note, the authenticator is not externalbrowser)*

*(MS Access 365 for Enterprise, 64-bit)*

Comment: You have to get some sample working connection strings. You also have to find out if the drivers they supply supports ODBC - they might not.

Comment: Thanks Albert, this is why I'm asking the question.  In my week's of searching, I have not found anyone who can supply a working sample connection string.  I already have ODBC installation that works (as I can connect to Snowflake through a browser or DBeaver using it).

Comment: Are you using the x32 bit odbc config in the control panel, or the x64 bit one? You want to use the x32 bit version for the odbc config panel. Also launch that config panel as adim, and also create a user or system DSN. For some strange reason a number of ODBC connector setups don't work with file DSN's. But always launch the odbc config with admin rights. (right click - run as admin). And as noted, make sure you launch the x32 bit version of odbc (assuming access x32).

Comment: So, I'm using 64 but office, and am currently using 64 bit odbc.  I am using a User DSN with appropriate config.

Comment: @JimT [ODBC connection string to Snowflake for Access Pass Thru Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532816/odbc-connection-string-to-snowflake-for-access-pass-thru-query)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, That one doesn't address the 64-bit issue for DNS-free pass through queries. In other words, you can have Access connect to Snowflake using 64-bit DNS-free queries, but the moment you try using it for Access pass-through queries nobody so far has been able to get that working. At least nobody who's active here has shared a way, and it's not been for a lack of trying. Let's see if anyone comes up with a way.

Comment: @JimT, it looks as if you've gotten close here. What happens if you specify (over in Snowflake) a default warehouse for the user you're using to connect from Accss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to those who may be interested, the below works for the pass through query connection string property:

```
ODBC;
driver={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};
server=xxxxxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.xxxxxxxxxx.snowflakecomputing.com;
database=xxxxxxxxxx;
warehouse=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
role=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
Uid=xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com;
Pwd=xxxxxxxxx;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Optional Connection Parameters](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#optional-connection-parameters)

> warehouse (Warehouse)
>
> Specifies the default warehouse to use for sessions initiated by the driver.

`WH=XYZ;` should rather be `WAREHOUSE=XYZ;`

Comment: Thanks Lukasz - The link looks like it might provide some answers.  Unfortunately, changing WH to WAREHOUSE did not work; same error.

Comment: @JimT Is the XYZ case sensitive? `WAREHOUSE="XYZ";`

Comment: I don't think so, I've tried it both ways.

Comment: @JimT Then the last attempt: `ALTER USER <user_name> SET DEFAULT_WAREHOUSE=XYZ;` and skip WAREHOUSE part from connection string