# Snowflake connection string provided by Azure Key Vault

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-keyvault

Here is my Snowflake connection in Python:

```
import snowflake.connector
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(user='someuser@somedomain.com',
password='somepassword',
account='someaccount',
warehouse='somewarehouse',
database='somedb',
schema='someschema'
authenticator='someauth')
```

It works fine, but now I need to store my connection details in Azure Key Vault and is far as I understand it will be coming back as a string, which I will need to feed into `snowflake.connector.connect()`

So I tried to convert connection parameters into string:

```
connection_string = "user=someuser@somedomain.com;password=somepassword;account=someaccount;authenticator=someauth;warehouse=somewarehouse;database = somedb"
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(connection_string)
```

but got back error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ca89ef96ad7d> in <module>
----> 1 ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(connection_string)

TypeError: Connect() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I also tried extracting python dictionary from string with `ast` library and feeding it into `snowflake.connector.connect()`, but got back the same error.

So is there way to solve it? Am I missing something conceptually?

Comment: If you know that **;**is a separator in your connection_string, can't you just split it by that separator and use each value of the list as one of the args in the connect method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if given references can help:

Snowflake connector variables are separate .we may need  to separate by split method.
Conn=Connection_string.split(‘;’) and use it in snowflake connector.
**Note** : For the ACCOUNT parameter, use your account identifier ,the account identifier **does not include** the `snowflakecomputing.com` domain name/ suffix. Snowflake automatically appends this when creating the connection.So it may work for snowflake connector.

So try giving connection variables first before and then use the variables in snowflake connector and connection string. Or
Try to include driver and server in the connection string by saving the complete connection string  including accountname, username, password, database, warehouse details in Azure Key Vault .

Sample connection string format :

```
"jdbc:snowflake://<accountname>.snowflakecomputing.com/?user=<username>&db=<database>&warehouse=<warehouse>&role=<myRole>"
```

**References:**

1. [Configuring the JDBC Driver — Snowflake Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#private-key-file-name-and-password-in-connection-string)
2. [ODBC connection string to Snowflake for Access Pass Thru Query -
   Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532816/odbc-connection-string-to-snowflake-for-access-pass-thru-query)
3. [azure-docs/connector-snowflake.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs
   · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/connector-snowflake.md)
4. [connect-snowflake-using-python-pyodbc-odbc-driver](https://dwgeek.com/connect-snowflake-using-python-pyodbc-odbc-driver-example.html/)